# Create a column in a table based on the rest of the row and other table

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have two tables, and I'd like to select a range of positions from one table for each row in the other table.

I've tried to relate the tables in order to get new information but it seems like there is no OUTER APPLY in MS Access. Here is my code:

```
    SELECT *
FROM [pred-predi_calculo-presi]
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP 1 [snptc_histo].POSICIONBUS
      FROM [snptc_histo]
      WHERE [snptc_histo].PATENTEBUS = [pred-predi_calculo-presi].PATENTE
        AND [snptc_histo].horaConsulta < [pred-predi_calculo-presi].'pasadaReal'
      ORDER BY [snptc_histo].horaConsulta DESC
    ) AS p
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP 1 [snptc_histo].POSICIONBUS
      FROM [snptc_histo]
      WHERE [snptc_histo].PATENTEBUS = [pred-predi_calculo-presi].PATENTE
        AND [snptc_histo].horaConsulta >= [pred-predi_calculo-presi].'pasadaReal'
      ORDER BY [snptc_histo].horaConsulta ASC
    ) AS n ;
```

I thought it'd be much easier to do this action with Java code (I have the algorithm in mind) and also more optimal, but I don't have the right tools like data structures or right "commands" to work with databases through Java (I'm a mathematician) and thus would need much more help. (Although I'm open to suggestions about the Java option.)
 Here's a sample data:

pred-predi_calculo-presi:

```
Id1 ID                       Paradero'horaPrediccion''pasadaReal'PREDICCION_NUEVA   PATENTE servicio
1   2016-12-13 17:36:50_T518    PA52    17:36:51       17:36:20      1579,242       CJRW-73    518
2   2016-12-13 17:36:50_T518    PA52    17:36:51       17:36:20      761,211        BJFB-79    518
3   2016-12-13 17:11:02_T518    PC475   17:17:53       17:16:34      1382,545       BFKC-47    518
4   2016-12-13 17:11:02_T518    PC475   17:17:53       17:16:34      695,283        CJRW-74    518
5   2016-12-13 17:11:03_T418    PC206   17:16:27       17:15:50      1210,033       ZN-6742    418
6   2016-12-13 17:11:03_T418    PC206   17:16:27       17:15:50      1407,741       ZN-5814    418
7   2016-12-13 17:16:41_T516    PD208   17:17:56       17:18:02      842,634        BJFY-17    516
```

snptc_histo:

```
PATENTEBUS  POSICIONBUS FECHAGPS
WA-9114     0           17:15:52
CJRW-83     3,64        17:15:52
ZN-3967     0,26        17:15:50
BJFV-89     11,06       17:15:51
BJFS-92     32,866      17:15:51
FLXJ-30     19,74       17:15:51
BJFR-52     9,55        17:15:50
CJRW-52     24,67       17:15:50
BJFR-94     14,75       17:15:49
CJRT-63     16,02       17:15:49
```

Comment: Hi; strategy changed; now I'm using access as interface and data source, but it seems like there is no OUTER APPLY command (no results in office support)

Comment: May be you could post some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: You may need to merge your accounts and have enough reputation to comment and vote. http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/116463/julio-maldonado-henr%C3%ADquez

Comment: @JulioMaldonadoHenríquez: ...and edit your question directly without peer review. Follow [these instructions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Comment: @JSapkota even when Julio Maldonado is unregistered?? I had a account when I asked but forgot to log in